# How to solve ini error for npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I just install node.js to my system. My node version is v8.10.0. When I try npm -v I get following error.

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ini'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ai8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:4:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you tried to  uninstall and reinstall npm?

Comment: @Veve yes i have tried uninstalling and reinstalling npm . but same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a same kind of issue before. I tried all the solutions even tried uninstalling and reinstalling node js. Finally, I tried by removing the node_modules from the user folder.
Then, run npm install.

This worked for me.

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 2):

delete node_modules and reinstall

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Use this link for further details. Hope this will help you.
[npm](https://github.com/npm/npm)

Comment: Yes I have tried removing the entire node_modules and but when i hit npm command I get those problem

Comment: try:

`npm remove -g sails`
`npm install -g sails`